# Celery worker grabs task while being on cool-down set by rate_limit

Tags: python, mongodb, queue, celery, rate-limiting

My task is consists of sequential requests (data from first request is needed for second and so on) to API which has rate limits for one host. So I've tried to get speed up by using Celery for managing several workers. But with several running workers tasks does not distributed evenly. So while there is free workers, task goes to worker on cool-down, which significantly reduces overall processing speed.

Code which demonstrate this problem:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', backend='mongodb', broker='mongodb://localhost:27017/celery')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ACKS_LATE = True,
    CELERYD_CONCURRENCY = 1,
    CELERYD_PREFETCH_MULTIPLIER = 1,
)

@app.task(rate_limit='10/m')
def mytask():
    return 'ok'
```

If you start several workers (with or without -Ofair option) and run following code:

```
while True:
    tasks.mytask.apply_async().get()
```

Tasks will not be distributed evenly and you can easily see that task almost every time goes to worker on coll-down.

That is right Celery configuration for this kind of problem?